# Unable to create different sheets in an excel file for different links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, openpyxl

I've written a script in python to parse some `tiles` and `links` of different tutorials from a webpage and finally write those in an excel file. I've used `openpyxl`. My script is doing fine If I consider to get all of the documents in a single sheet. However, I've used three links in my scraper to scrape data from. My goal is to write those scraped documents in three different sheets in an excel file. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from lxml.html import fromstring
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
wb.active
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

storage ={
'http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/year/2011.htm',
'http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/year/2012.htm',
'http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/year/2013.htm'
}

def get_docs(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    root = fromstring(response.text)
    for item in root.cssselect(".woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"):
        title = item.cssselect("a")[0].text
        title_link = item.cssselect("a")[0].attrib['href']
        print(title,title_link)
        ws.append([title,title_link])
        wb.save("tuts.xlsx")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for tut_link in storage:
        get_docs(tut_link)
```

Once again, my script is able to scrape the documents and write those in a single sheet in an excel file but I wish to get the documents written in three different sheets (each sheet is for each link) in an excel file.

Comment: What don't you know how to do?

Comment: So you have got nothing better to do without making irritating remarks @Charlie Clark. Btw, the problem is already solved.

Comment: Please review the rules on asking questions.

Comment: Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#write-a-workbook shows you how to create sheets. Your question should have started there.

Comment: If I was unable to bring the clarity about my question, how did I get the exact answer I wanted? Turn out that You made a harsh comment in the first place and got even harsh reply which is why you can't take this. Let us ignore this childlike behavior. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code returns a sheet that looks like this:
~[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXkoI.png)

Before your for loop, we create a new sheet to put the results in.  We then iterate save the results to that sheet.

The code:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from lxml.html import fromstring
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
wb.active

storage ={
'http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/year/2011.htm',
'http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/year/2012.htm',
'http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/year/2013.htm'
}

def get_docs(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    root = fromstring(response.text)
    # Create a worksheet with the title of the year.
    ws = wb.create_sheet(link[37:-4])
    for item in root.cssselect(".woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"):
        title = item.cssselect("a")[0].text
        title_link = item.cssselect("a")[0].attrib['href']
        print(title,title_link)
        ws.append([title,title_link])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for tut_link in storage:
        get_docs(tut_link)
    sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
    wb.remove_sheet(sheet)
    wb.save("tuts.xlsx")
```

Comment: You are awesome @Spence Wetjen!!!! Your solution is what I was expecting. Just one thing: is it possible to kick out that blank sheet from the workbook. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: @novice-coder Sure.  Updated the solution to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a zillion. I wish I could upvote your solution thousand times. Thanks again.